# Finding n in equivalence between two permutations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

Find the value(s) of n: 2P(n, 2)+50 = P(2n, 2)

For 2P(n, 2)+50 I simplified to 2(n)(n-1)+50. For P(2n, 2) I can't get any simpler than $2n\times(2n-1)\times...\times(n+1)\times n\times(n-1)$ and I'm stuck.

BTW what's the LaTex for pick notation?

Comment: If you mean $P(n,2)=\binom n2$, then it is  "\binom{n}{2}" between $ signs.

Comment: @Berci that's for "combinations", no?

Comment: @Celeritas yes, you are probably right.

Comment: By pick notation, I assume OP means choice notation. Choice notation equals binomial notation, the standard $\binom{x}{y}=\frac{x!}{(x-y)!}$, so @Berci is right

Answer (score 1):

If $P(n,2)$ is $n(n-1)$ then you have $$2n(n-1)+50 =2n(2n-1)$$ which is a quadratic you can solve.

You will get a positive and negative answer.  Presumably you want the positive integer as your solution.

Comment: I don't follow. Why do you randomly say P(n,2)=n-1?

Comment: @Celeritas I did not say $n-1$ but $n(n-1)$. See  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#In_combinatorics

Comment: I don't follow. Why do you randomly say P(n,2)=n(n-1)?

Comment: I guess then $P(n,k)$ wants to denote the number '*$k$-permuations of $n$*' which is $n!/(n-k)!$.

Comment: @Celeritas -  Permutations: choose $k$ items from $n$ where the order in which you choose them matters.  So for $P(n,2)$ choose one of the $n$ and then choose one from the remaining $n-1$ in a total of $n \times (n-1)$ different ways.

Comment: I think I'm starting to see your point a little bit. So P(n,2)=2n(n-1)+50, agreed but I don't see how P(n,2)=2n(2n-1)? Also you speak of solving the quadratic. We don't know what the equation is equal to i.e. 0?

Comment: $P(2n,2)=2n(2n-1)$ because you choose $k$ items from $2n$ where the order in which you choose them matters. So  choose one of the $2n$ and then choose one from the remaining $2n−1$

Comment: @Henry By solving 2n(n-1)+50=2n(2n-1), you expand, giving 2n^2-2n+50=4n^2-2n, and moving everything to left side gives -2n^2+50=0, which is trivial to solve

Comment: @DanielGeyfman Indeed, though I had left those steps for the original poster to take

Comment: Sorry Henry, I meant to put @Celeritas in response to his question about what the equation is equal to, I accidentally put your name. Sorry